# Type Bounds and Pattern Matching in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching, type-parameter

Let's say I have the following:

```
trait Person {
  val name: String
}
case class Student(val name: String) extends Person
case class Teacher(val name: String, students: List[Student]) extends Person
```

I'd like a function function that could take any `Person` implementation, match on the specific type, and then return the most specific type possible. (I know this might not be the smartest thing, but bear with me.) Let's say something like:

```
def teacherGreeting(teacher: Teacher): (Teacher, String) = {
  val names = teacher.students.map(_.name).mkString(", ")
  (teacher, s"Hello ${teacher.name}, your students are $names")
}

def greet[P <: Person](person: P): (P, String) = person match {
  case Student(name) => (person, s"Hello $name")
  case Teacher(name, students) => teacherGreeting(person)
}
```

But then I get:

```
<console>:19: error: type mismatch;
 found   : P
 required: Teacher
             case Teacher(name, students) => teacherGreeting(person)
                                                         ^
```

If I have the logic of `teacherGreeting` inside of `greet`, I don't have any problems. So, why doesn't the compiler know that `P` in this branch of the code *must* be a `Teacher`?

If I use the matched value:

```
def greet[P <: Person](person: P): (P, String) = person match {
  case Student(name) => (person, s"Hello $name")
  case teacher @ Teacher(name, students) => teacherGreeting(teacher)
}
```

The error just happens later, with the result of `teacherGreeting`, instead of the input:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : (Teacher, String)
 required: (P, String)
             case teacher @ Teacher(name, students) => teacherGreeting(teacher)
                                                                  ^
```

Is there no way to avoid casting?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you compile `greet(p)`, the compiler has to infer the type `P` in

```
def greet[P <: Person](person: P): (P, String)
```

If you then defined a subclass of Person and call greet on that an instance:

```
class Parent(val name: String) extends Person
val parent = new Parent("Joe")
val (p, greeting) = greet(parent)
```

The inferred type P is determined at compile time, it does not depend on the runtime type of parent. So the compiler would have to infer `P` as `Parent`: `greet[Parent](parent)`.

But then how would these expressions be typed? In order to type check, since `P` is `Parent`, they have to be of type `(Parent, String)`:

```
case teacher @ Teacher(name, students) => teacherGreeting(teacher)
case Teacher(name, students) => teacherGreeting(person)
```

In the first case, the return type of `teacherGreeting(teacher)` is `(Teacher, String)`. And `Teacher` is not a `Parent`. The return type does not match.

In the second case, you are calling `teacherGreeting(person: Parent)` so it is wrong type for the argument.

When you say you don't have a problem if you inline the body of `teacherGreeting` inside the second case, that is probably because you return `(person, "str")`. And in that case `person` would be of type `P` for sure. But when you pass it through `teacherGreeting`, the compiler does not know that you are returning the passed argument of type `P`. For all we know you could be returning `Teacher("another", List())`.

**Edit:** so thinking on how to preserve the type `P` here is a (cumbersome) way to go about it. You want to retain the type through the `teacherGreeting` call. This can be done like this. Use a type parameter `Q` that will be inferred as the `P` from `greet`:

```
def teacherGreeting[Q <: Teacher](teacher: Q): (Q, String) = {
  val names = teacher.students.map(_.name).mkString(", ")
  (teacher, s"Hello ${teacher.name}, your students are $names")
}
```

Tell the compiler that `teacher` is a `P` *and* a `Teacher`:

```
def greet[P <: Person](person: P): (P, String) = person match {
  case Student(name) => (person, s"Hello $name")
  case teacher: (P with Teacher) => teacherGreeting(teacher)
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a very useful explanation!

Answer (score 2):

Actually it can be even shorter, cause i don't see any reason in unapplying teacher in PatMat:

```
def greet(person: Person): (Person, String) = person match {
  case Student(name)    => (person, s"Hello $name")
  case teacher: Teacher => teacherGreeting(teacher)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use type classes for this:

```
trait Greeter[P <: Person] {
  def greet(person: P): (P, String)
}

object Greeter {
  implicit object studentGreeter extends Greeter[Student] {
    def greet(student: Student) = (student, s"Hello ${student.name}")
  }
  implicit object teacherGreeter extends Greeter[Teacher] {
    def greet(teacher: Teacher) = {
      val names = teacher.students.map(_.name).mkString(", ")
      (teacher, s"Hello ${teacher.name}, your students are $names")
    }
  }
}

def greet[P <: Person](person: P)(implicit gr: Greeter[P]) = gr.greet(person)
```

A note aside: You don't really need the type-bound on `Person`, it's rather for documentation / prevention of abuse.

Answer (score 1):

Like the other answer, I wanted to motivate the error message.

Curiously, the inferred type is happy for the extractor pattern and unhappy with the constructor pattern (that is, if `Teacher` is a case class, where it sees `t.type` instead of `P`).

```
package teachers

trait Person {
  def name: String
  override def toString = name
}
case class Student(name: String) extends Person
//case class Teacher(name: String, students: List[Student]) extends Person
class Teacher(val name: String, val students: List[Student]) extends Person
object Teacher {
  def apply(name: String, students: List[Student]) = new Teacher(name, students)
  def unapply(teacher: Teacher) = Some((teacher.name, teacher.students))
}
class Substitute(name: String, students: List[Student]) extends Teacher(name, students)
object Substitute {
  def apply(name: String, teacher: Teacher) = new Substitute(name, teacher.students)
  def unapply(sub: Substitute) = Teacher.unapply(sub)
}

object Test extends App {
  def teacherGreeting[A <: Teacher](teacher: A, duration: String): (A, String) = {
    val names = teacher.students.map(_.name).mkString(", ")
    (teacher, s"Hello ${teacher.name}, your students for the $duration are $names")
  }

  def greet[P <: Person](person: P): (P, String) = person match {
    case Student(name)                  => (person, s"Sit down and be quiet, $name")
    case s @ Substitute(name, students) => teacherGreeting(s, "day")
    case t @ Teacher(name, students)    => teacherGreeting(t, "year")
  }
  import reflect.runtime.universe._
  def show[P <: Person : TypeTag](person: P) = implicitly[TypeTag[P]].tpe.typeSymbol.name

  val mary = Teacher("Mary", List("Dick","Jane").map(Student))
  val (who, msg) = greet(Substitute("Bob", mary))
  Console println s"$who is a ${show(who)}"
  Console println msg
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking you don't really need a generic type on `greet`.  When you change your `greet` to:

```
def greet(person: Person): (Person, String) = person match {
  case Student(name) => (person, s"Hello $name")
  case teacher @ Teacher(name, students) => teacherGreeting(teacher)
}
```

Everything works just fine.